# Left side menu within UISplitView Master Controller

Tags: swift, uisplitviewcontroller

I have replaced the original Master of a UISplitView that was a UITableView with a UIViewController and now I want to let the UIViewController have the functionality of its own left side menu, is this possible? I am a little confused on how to go about implementing something like this. Would I have a custom UITableView and then a button action that would fade in this table view over my Master UIViewController? I am fairly new to Swift & iOS so I am really just looking for direction on how to attack this problem.

Comment: Yes, you can replace the UITableView to any other UIViewController as you like. If you trying to do something like navigation drawer, you can have a look on this link: [MMDrawerController](https://github.com/mutualmobile/MMDrawerController)

Comment: @Lee I will take a look at this. This could be embedded in my UIViewController even if the UIViewController is the Master of my Split View?

Comment: Its okay to use any kind of view as master of split view